Rails 7 chart.js upgrade from version 2.9.4 to 4.4.4 - Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
I am trying to upgrade chart.js from version 2.9.4 to 4.4.4.
Javascript is managed by Yarn tool.
Package.json file
`"chart.js": "^4.4.4",`

Application.rb file had this path for version 2.9.3 which seems not applicable for version 4.4.4 as per this doc,
//= require chart.js/dist/Chart

Please suggest path to include in application.js file for chart.js version 4.4.4.
Tried to download and include files in vendor folder but still failing.
It's throwing this error,
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined


This path is required for upgraded version - //= require chart.js/dist/chart.umd.js        Locally, rails app is generating charts. But when deploying to AWS EC2 Jenkins build is failing with this error during rails assets:precompilation
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (=)
